# How to Get a List of Class Attribute

Tags: python-3.x

there is a list of instances from the same class, and i want to extract a certain attribute of every instance and build up a new list

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

l = [Test(1), Test(2), Test(3), Test(4)]
```

something like that, and i want to get a list which result is `[1, 2, 3, 4]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do it would probably be like this:

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

l = [Test(1), Test(2), Test(3), Test(4)]
res = [inst.x for inst in l] # [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

or just do it from the start:

```
l = [Test(1).x, Test(2).x, Test(3).x, Test(4).x]
```

Comment: you mean res = [Test.x for Test in l]?

Comment: No. That would do something completely different and probably throw an exception because `Test` is a class.